# How to identify my self that my question is too localized and how can I get answers for those questions?

Tags: discussion

I am experienced that questions might get closed if they are too localized. I have seen FAQs and I found the *"If the question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet then it is too localized. please make the question more broadly applicable".*

And may I know on what basis that you measure the "localized" factor of a question? If you ask me, the question that I am posting will be useful to the average non-native english user or an average person from our country at least.  At such situation it is useful to the many people who are kind of me and who are at my knowledge level.

It is not good that question is getting closed. I would like to avoid my question get closed stating "too localized"How to identify my self that my question is too localized and how can I get answers for those questions? What research I can do and what care that I can take before posting such questions to avoid closing?

Answer (score 3):

There's really nothing you could have done to prevent that question from being closed.

You did exactly what you ought to do: you ran across an odd usage, you took it to be an idiom you had not previously encountered, you searched diligently for a definition of the idiom, you reported your efforts and asked for elucidation. You could not know that in fact the usage was not idiomatic at all but was a representation of the speech of someone whose command of English was greatly inferior to your own. The question was closed because the phrase in question isn't English, just as we close questions which turn on typographical errors or odd poetic metaphors or idiolectic (personally eccentric) uses.

Closing the question thus implies no criticism of your efforts; on the contrary, it's an admirable question and has been upvoted. It just means that once the answer has been supplied there's nothing to be gained by pursuing the matter further.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to caution you about reading too much into the *reason* that a question gets closed. When someone votes to close a question, they are presented a choice of five options. It's not uncommon to see quite a bit of overlap between some of these choices, to the point where it's hard to pick one, but the system forces a choice of one and only one answer. So, even though a voter might be thinking, "This kind of falls under *general reference*, but I could see it being deemed *too localized*, too," they can only select one. I wrote more about this on an earlier meta answer; you can read about it [HERE](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3093).

As for how to prevent such closures, I think sometimes they are unavoidable. If you've done a lot of research to answer your own question, but never managed to find that "missing piece," it could be that, once your question is asked, there's an obvious answer, so the question gets closed. That happens every now and then, even to [the best of the best](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/89618). Typically, when that happens, the question does get answered somewhere (perhaps in a comment), so at least the mystery is solved, and you won't have to toss and turn at night, wondering about the answer to your question.  Remember, in cases like this, closure is meant to be a neutral activity, which is why you won't lose any reputation points when a question that you asked is eventually closed. So, there's no need to [make a face](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95774) – just keep up the good work, and everything will turn out alright in the long run.